# Cannot find module @angular/core upon importing additional modules

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-code, angular-material

I have been banging my head for almost 10 hours on this but cannot resolve.

I have created a new Angular project which when I serve runs fine but as soon as I install and try to import material module, the compiler starts throwing error as

> error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.

This error goes away as I remove the import statement from my app module

I have tried reinstalling node, @angular/cli and all the packages but it does not work.

If it helps, `package.json` has

```
{
  "name": "firebase",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.8",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.8",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Happy to provide whatever information is needed.

Comment: what is your baseUrl in tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember similar thing caused by angular cdk, can you try the following commands?

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: inside my project directory?

Comment: windows or what os ? just remove node modules and do npm install

Comment: doing just npm install inside my project directory solved it. Can you please elaborate your answer why this might have happened despite of reinstalling everything?

Comment: most likely it could be reference node_modules package missed in the angular project.